# Problem show video with kurento media server running in docker

Tags: javascript, webrtc, kurento, simplewebrtc, kurento-media-server

### Description:

I am building a video call app via web browser, a simple version of Googlemeet. I use **WebRTC, Kurento, React Frontend, Express Backend, Socket.io Signaling Server**

### My code to connect kurento server:

```
const io = new socketIO.Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:5000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

const argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
  default: {
    as_uri: "http://localhost:3000",
    ws_uri: "ws://localhost:8888/kurento",
  },
});`


function getKurentoClient(cb) {
  if (kurentoClient !== null) {
    return cb(null, kurentoClient);
  } else {
    return kurento(argv.ws_uri, (error, _client) => {
      if (error) {
        callback(error);
      } else {
        kurentoClient = _client;
        cb(null, _client);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

### Problem:

The videos/audio just not show at all even when I permitted.

### What I Tried:

1. Clone the example project in kurento's website.
2. Update the newer version of kurento-client and other package.
3. Read the docs of kurento.

### The result of my tries:

1. These projects are so old, that I am not sure they still work
2. Still get the same result after upgrading/downgrading packages version.
3. When reading the docs, I found some methods are missing in explanation, like the  **WebRTCEnpoint.connect** method, that makes me wonder if it's the reason why the media just does not connect to each other.

### What I want to achieve:

- I really want understand more about my situation and get the videos/audios to work.
- I hope someone can point me to a recently example or just explain how the connect method works so. Many thanks